# Why does my computer only boot successfully after restarting my UPS (battery backup)?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard

So, before Windows 10 October 2018 (1809) update my computer ran flawlessly and played Fallout 4 with mods without any problems. If there's any crash, the computer would simply go to desktop.

After the October 2018 update, I noticed that my computer "restarted" itself while running Fallout 4 with mods. The CPU turns on but my monitor goes to power saving. I tried pressing the restart button on the front panel, but the monitor still gives me black screen.

But here is the weird part: It can only be fixed by turning off my UPS (APC 600W) then turning it back on, then start my PC. Only then CPU and monitor go back to normal. Also, I learned that my Fallout 4 save is "corrupted", so loading that current save will produce the same problem with my PC. I deleted the current save and load the previous save, it is fine now.

The problem isn't with Fallout 4 save being corrupt. I've played this game since Windows 7 never had any problems regarding "monitor goes to power saving by corrupted save file".

What is going on with my PC? Is my motherboard or RAM dying?

Edit: if i do office work or video editing, watching youtube/movies my PC runs very well. Only for select few video games. (For example: My Time at Portia game save was corrupted before, same issue. I deleted the save, started a new game and it works great again).

My system specs are:

- **OS**: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- **Motherboard**: MSI H97 GAMING 3 (MS-7918) (SOCKET 0)
- **CPU**: Intel Core i5 4670K @ 3.40GH Haswell 22nm Technology
- **GPU**: 4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 (ZOTAC International)
- **Storage**: 953GB V-GEN03SM19EG1TP3X4IT (Unknown (SSD))
- **PSU**: Corsair CX600 (Green)
- **UPS Backup Battery**: APC 600W

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Glitches are always possible. Do `chkdsk` and check the disk's SMART data. If everything is ok, only worry if it starts happening regularly.

Comment: I suggest backing up your important data, ruling out the UPS' involvement by plugging directly into the wall and repeating your test.

Comment: This sounds like a power supply issue. Basically, restarting the UPS is probably analogous to unplugging your computer and then plugging it back in. You can test this by doing exactly that: Don't restart your UPS, just unplug the computer and monitor for 30 seconds or so and then plug it back in.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but i did what you say though unplugging the comp and monitor from UPS for a minute then plugging it directly into the socket, same issue. Only from this UPS that my computer can only boot perfectly. What a weird bond. I could restart the comp from the desktop though, but not from the front panel nor will it boot properly upon restart by itself. If this is in fact a PSU issue then why nothing happened when i was doing office work for hours? Also, same games run pretty well too..

Comment: Games can be much more power hungry than office work.  It could be that the power-related problem doesn't present itself until the demand reaches a certain load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i have replaced the Power Supply with Corsair RMX Series 550W 80+ Gold. My computer runs perfectly fine at the moment and no crashes in Fallout 4 and Call to Arms. Lesson learned, if computer reboots mid-game it could be PSU and to purchase UPS (backup battery) higher than my PSU wattage, silly me for purchasing the UPS with an equal wattage as my previous PSU.

Thank you all for participating in helping me solve this riddle.
PS: I am a newbie in "computer" so there's a lot to learn.